# Can not start Integrated WebLogic server in Oracle Jdeveloper 12c

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I got homework to create Oracle ADF applications according to the instructions on oracle.com, specifically there: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37547_01/tutorials/tut_rich_app/tut_rich_app_2.html
But in step 10, I can not start IntegratedWeblogic server.

Log with fails is there: http://www.sendspace.com/file/v9l7vy

My bare idea is diacritical marks and space in my Windows username 'Petr Mojžíš'. I use Microsoft account to login to Windows, which create this anomaly.

I use Windows 8.1 64bit in English version and Oracle JDeveloper 12c.

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Did you add any jars to weblogic libs?

Comment: Manually no. Only installed Oracle JDeveloper and that's all. What do you think your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set a system environment variable `JDEV_USER_HOME` and point it to a path in your directory `D:\JDEV_USER_HOME` . But this way the Jdeveloper related information is stored in the `D:\JDEV_USER_HOME` rather than `AppData` under user directory .

Comment: It works! Thank you. I followed these instructions: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/jdev/OJDIG/post_install.htm#A1147484 - step 3.7.2. Set variable as JDEV_USER_DIR and value as C:\JDeveloper\mywork. Unfortunately, my application throws a Internal server error 500 when viewing the page. But this is already another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Modify %HOME%\oracle_common\common\bin\commEnv.cmd file setting USER_MEM_ARGS environment variable after ":continue" tag and re-create default domain again from Application Servers view on JDeveloper.

SET USER_MEM_ARGS=-Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:MaxHeapSize=512m

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced a situation with the integrated weblogic server goes to the point when it says it is  and it stops there, jdeveloper does not exit task. Making it impossible to deploy apps.

Possible solution.
It seems that it might have to do with Environment settings. 
I changed the JAVA_HOME to point to the one in %ORACLE_HOME%\oracle_common\jdk and set the path to %JAVA_HOME%\bin and it seems to solve the issue.
Previously I was on
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

and now on 
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have your Weblogic in directory that has both special characters and spaces C:\Users\Petr Mojžíš\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\DefaultDomain

In order to overcome this, Close your JDeveloper, create a new Environment variables JDEV_USER_HOME which points to a directory without any spaces or special characters. Open JDeveloper again and you should be good to go.